# CSS adding styling class to html

Tags: css

Simple question, do people think it's a good idea to add styling class in the html?

I can add a class like `.font-bold` in the html and then in the css have

```
.font-bold{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Very simple but I'm thinking it's counter productive as if i need to change it I have to search through and change the class names in the html.

Comment: This is very common. But maybe use `.b` so it's easier?

Comment: @Purag or a `<strong>` element?

Comment: _Very simple but I'm thinking it's counter productive as if i need to change it I have to search through and chnage the class names in the html._ This will also happen if you're using inline style or `<strong>`.

Comment: @Vucko: There's a difference between `strong` and bold, actually. `strong` tends to be more fluid...if you plan on emphasizing in a way other than bold, you might use `strong` instead of a class just to bold text.

Comment: This question should be re-opened as it is actually a relevant and good question asking about downsides of a common, but questionable practice in web development.

Comment: Should be rephrased. Asking about the drawbacks and benefits of each is a better question. :)

Comment: Okay, so this was reopened, but I'm expecting one of the people who voted for reopening to come and edit this question because it is still asking for opinionated answers.

Comment: Sorry, bold was probably a bad example. It could be 'rd' as the class name then `color: red;` as the class. i was thinking more is it a bad idea to fix styling in this way to the html element.